# forceUpdate VS forceReload

Tags: reactjs

I'm wondering what is the difference between `forceUpdate()` and `forceReload()` in ReactJS.

Tried to find some documentation about that but couldn't find some on `forceReload()`-

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you saw it, but `forceReload` isn't a part of React. You presumably couldn't find documentation because there isn't any -- if I search for `"forceReload" react` right now, this question comes up first.

If you want to make a component rerender without changing its state or props, you should call `forceUpdate`.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it was a mistake in React API